# Editing Property Functon of a recursive Property

Tags: python, class, recursion, properties

I have a function which functionality can be described with this code:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "testing"

    @property
    def first(self):
        return Test()


test = Test()
print(test.first)
print(test.first.first)
```

(Output)

```
testing
testing
```

Basicly, it has a recursive property.
I want to edit the property function of the class, but save the recursion:
(This doesnt work but explains my idea)

```py
def edit_property(test_class):

    @test_class.property
    def first(test_class):
        return test_class.first + " test"

edit_property(test)
```

The result of this code would be (if it would work)

```
testing test
testing test test
```

Comment: It's not really recursive. Every use of `first` operates on a different instance of `Test`.

Comment: Anywa, my goal is still the same.

Comment: you would have to run recursion inside `first()` but problem is your `first` returns `return Test()` but it doesn't keep access to this new `Test()` so it will no have access to this `Test()` to change it. All idea seems wrong. Every `first()` creates separated object and you can't change then recursivly,

Comment: your `first()` is even worst - using two times `a = test.first` and `b = test.first` you creates two separated objects.

Comment: another wrong idea: `first()` returns object `Test()`, not string, and only when you run it in `print()` then it automatically runs `str()` to convert it to string. You would have to manually convert to string `str(test_class.first) + " test"` but this will only create new string, it will not change text inside class `Text()` - you would have to keep text in some variable `self.text` and `__str__` should do `return self.text` and `edit` should modify this `self.text`. Frankly, all your code is wrong - from beginning to the end.

Comment: And I don't understand why you want to get two `test` (`testing test test`) from `print(test.first.first)` - it gets text only from last `first`, not from `test`, nor `test.first`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,value='') -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "testing" + self.value

    @property
    def first(self):
        return Test(self.value + ' test')


test = Test()
print(test.first)
print(test.first.first.first)
```